# "Read More" button stopped working in PHP, MySQL CMS

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I want to display little amount of text when users come to my blog that's why I've made a "Read More" button to display few texts by cutting off the length of the text and the button was working fine until today when I add a new post via TinyMCE editor I saw that "Read More" button stopped working. While inspecting the error when I disable the function then the "Read More" button comes alive and the link to post is working fine but I'm unable to cut off the length please help me resolve this problem.

I'm using TinyMCE as editor for adding new posts.
This is index.php file.

```
<?php include("includes/db.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

    <!-- Navigation -->

    <?php include("includes/navigation.php"); ?>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <?php 

                    $per_page = 3;

                    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {

                        $page = $_GET['page'];
                    }
                    else {

                        $page = "";
                    }

                    if($page =="" || $page == 1) {

                        $page_1 = 0;
                    }
                    else {

                        $page_1 = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;
                    }

                    $post_query_count = "SELECT * FROM posts";
                    $find_count = mysqli_query($connection, $post_query_count);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($find_count);

                    $count = ceil($count / $per_page);

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";
                    $select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts_query)) {

                        $post_id = $row['post_id'];
                        $post_title = $row['post_title'];
                        $post_user = $row['post_user'];
                        $post_date = $row['post_date'];
                        $post_image = $row['post_image'];
                        $post_content = $row['post_content'];
                        $post_status = $row['post_status'];

                        if($post_status == 'published') {

                 ?>   

                <!-- First Blog Post -->
                <h2>
                    <a href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a>
                </h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    by <a href="index.php"><?php echo $post_user; ?></a>
                </p>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <?php echo $post_date; ?></p>
                <hr>
                <a href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/<?php echo $post_image; ?>" alt="">
                </a>
                <hr>
                <?php echo string_length_cutoff($post_content, 320, '........'); ?>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

                <hr>

                <?php  

                    } }

                 ?>


            </div>

            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->

            <?php include("includes/sidebar.php"); ?>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <ul class="pager">

            <?php 

                for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) { 

                    if($i == $page) {

                        echo "<li><a class='active_link' href='index.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<li><a href='index.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";                        
                    }
                }
             ?>
        </ul>

 <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

This function below is stored in functions.php file

```
function string_length_cutoff($post_content, $limit, $subtext = '...') {
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts_query)) {
            $post_content = $row['post_content'];
        }
    return (strlen($post_content) > $limit) ? substr($post_content, 0, ($limit-strlen('subtext'))).$subtext : $post_content;
    }
```

Some Screenshots of the actual problem

[Read More Button not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkeJr.jpg)

[Inspecting read more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhis.jpg)

[read more inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2sg7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think database query is needed. Removed it.

Change your function to:

```
function string_length_cutoff($post_content, $limit, $subtext = '...') {
    $post_content = strip_tags($post_content, '<img>');
    return ((strlen($post_content) > $limit) ? substr($post_content, 0, $limit).$subtext : $post_content);
}
```

Comment: Updated the function.

Comment: I've updated the function as you mentioned but the problem persists partially! In Some of the posts still, the read more button is inactive!

Comment: Must be something with the contents of your posts.

Comment: here are the screenshots https://www.flickr.com/gp/157873079@N02/si9466

Comment: I'm copying content from some random blogs and those blogs have their own content format and then I'm posting those content via TinyMCE editor. Copy pasting those contents changing the format of the "Read More" button.

Comment: You're awesome! It does solve the problem :) Thanks a lot man! Is there any other way I can be in touch with you besides Stack Overflow?

Comment: What's your email?

Comment: I'll send you an email today, so you'll know my email.